# jquery plugin for dropdown from select or list

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need a lightweight jquery plugin to build up a dropdown. I need this to work with both a source **<select>** or **<ul>**, this could be one or two separate plugins. The dropdown displayed needs to display the contents in **multiple columns** - I've only seen one plugin do this (http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) which is a great plugin but does more than I need and doesn't work for regular <select>.

Are there any plugins out there already that do this? I'm faced with rolling out a new one if I can't find an existing one. Also if anyone has any ideas on the best way to approach writing a plugin of this nature I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

This one uses  tags only, but meant to be an rss feed selector. You could use it as a base for your own plugin. [Jquery Feed Menus](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2008/10/jquery-feed-menus/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something super lightweight, then you can take a look at [Pretty Dropdowns](https://thdoan.github.io/pretty-dropdowns/). It converts `<select>` elements into a `<ul>` that you can style any way you want; with enough effort, you can even format it to display in multiple columns.